# Detecting touchdown, touchup, touchmove events across 4x4 iOS tiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, swipe, gesture

I am working on a game for iOS that looks a bit like the 'Boggle' board game, basically a 4x4 grid of numbers that you can swipe across with a touch down, touch move and touch up event structure that should return back to the main program the id/content of the 'tiles' swiped as well as 'select' them so that the user has visual feedback that they have been selected (this is my question...how to achieve this). A tile is something that could either be a button or label.

I was able to pull this off on the Windows Phone and PC platform with touch down/up/move events associated with the form itself, the notion of being 'directly over' or pushing 'down', 'moving across' or 'up' a label, and found it simple to hook up the events with the associated down/up/move actions, but can't seem to figure out how to do this on iOS, despite researching gestures as well as the touchup/down/move paradigms and creating several different gesture projects that haven't worked the way I found them to in Windows: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-2.aspx
  I am guessing labels should be used instead of buttons, but am open to using either. Right now, I have implemented the game with simple button touches, but the game loses a lot of the modern UI feel and natural UI constraints when you can't select a set of adjacent labels with a single swipe. Would *really* appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple!

```
/* Lots of code that didn't work, see old version if you want */
```

No, it wasn't that simple. It seems like UIButton steels the events..

..so I made a UIView subclass, with UILabels and custom touch handling (as Clever Error's answer also pointed out), posted on GitHub: https://github.com/LeonardPauli/LPSwipeableInputMatrixView

Tested and working. But not at all perfect. Should be pretty simple to remake, through.

Good luck! :)

Comment: When I tried the 2d solution, found a bug in the j iterator: (int j=0; j<cols; i++) //should be j++ and also, when I ran the code, the form is blank. When I tried it with my existing buttons, the events only seemed to fire when I started by clicking on a button, and it only worked for a single button, so I am still not able to make it work.

Comment: Here is the app I am trying to port over. It is on Windows Phone and Windows 8 PC store, trying to get to iOS in the next month... http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mathament/767c3a38-0288-467f-b693-b15b408a2960

Comment: Would you like to collaborate a bit?

Comment: Ok, I've now created a somewhat working pice of code, will upload it to GitHub soon.

Comment: Edited! Made it with core graphics. Maybe not the best choice. Maybe should remake with labels as @CleverError said...

Comment: I appreciate all the work here, Leonard. I tested the code and am struggling to figure out some basic stuff like which button was swiped over and its content/label value, how to implement with existing buttons rather than programmatically generated ones, etc... I have just been at iOS dev for a few weeks, so am not able to figure it out yet. Thanks again for all the effort!

Comment: Ok! Remade the code and updated the repo (https://github.com/LeonardPauli/MYSwipeableInputMatrixView)! The readme will answer the most of your questions! If you like, you know you can upvote and accept this answer? Also, do you mind if I continue to develop this code to another app (Similar to yours, but with another "game logic") and release it to the AppStore? If so, I could add a link to your app from mine when it's done. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Leonard. Really appreciate your efforts here. You are a brilliant dude!!! Feel free to use the UI idea however it suits you, and lets exchange game links when you are done with your app twitter.com/mathament. Would love to stay in touch if you can to bounce ideas off of you. I have some interesting game ideas. Shoot me a note if you have time: mikewilm@live.com

Comment: Leonard, how would I programmatically limit the number of swiped squares to say 3 or 4 squares?

Comment: Absolutely! Sending an email soon!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `GameBoardView` that is a subclass of `UIView`. This would then have all the labels in your 4x4 grid as a subviews. Then in your `GameBoardView`, you could implement the following methods to handle touch events.

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

These methods are in [`UIResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is the superclass for [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and are meant to be overridden so you can do your own touch based logic.

Comment: I am not sure how to subclass a UI View, but found this article, so I will try it and see if that is what the 1st answer was talking about: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view